# HyperV - responsive VMs

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm new to Hyper-V. We have provisioned some good server hardware (12 CPU cores (24 vCPUs), 128GB RAM - for future growth) and imported 6 existing Windows 2003/2008 servers all of which host websites. All VMs have enough resources and are quite fast, but only when they are active. If a VM is quiet for some time the first responses are very slow. This is true for both web requests and RDP activity. If for example I RDP to a VM which has been quiet for some time, I get to the desktop screen, click the Start button, I have to wait for a few seconds before the Start button expands.

Is there any way I can configure Hyper-V VMs to be highly responsive even after a period of inactivity? It seems illogical to me that on such a powerful underutilised hardware I have to wait for first responses.

Comment: Are your virtual machines using Dynamic Memory? If so, what is the minimum RAM set to for the affected virtual machines? What is the Memory buffer configured to? How do you have the virtual machine pagefile configured?

Comment: I started with Dynamic Memory, but then turned it off on all VMs thinking that it might be affecting performance. VMs have enough RAM ranging from 2GB to 16GB.

Comment: Re the VM pagefiles. All VM Windows Servers have been built long time ago with default pagefile configuration. So to be honest I haven't paid any attention to pagefiles.

Comment: I don't think that's specific to Hyper-V. My (Windows) laptop does that...

Comment: I apologise for being a bit misleading with my previous comment. Now I'm pretty confident that after turning Dynamic Memory off the VMs responsiveness is quite improved. It looks like that is all I needed to do.